# Java code exits after some seconds due to concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency

I am writing the same code on tutorial. But in tutorial the program never exits, my in my computer it exits after 4 seconds. Why?
tutorial with exact time where this code is shown: https://youtu.be/vzBw1LPupnA?t=169

```
public class Main {
    private static boolean stopRequested;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(() -> {
            int i = 0;
            while (!stopRequested) {
                i++;
                System.out.println("i = " + i);
            }
        });
        backgroundThread.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stopRequested = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the print statement and try again.

Comment: @RealSkeptic It may not stop. You have a race here. A lot of outcomes are permissible. Including the program not stopping. But it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 5):

The reason that you are seeing different behavior on your machine and in the video is because the program has unspecified behavior.  (Or to put it another way, it is not thread-safe.)

You have two threads accessing and updating a shared variable without taking the *necessary steps* that will guarantee that changes made by one thread are visible to the other.  What happens in that case **is not specified**.

- In some cases (e.g. on some platforms) the changes will be visible, either immediately or within a short time.
- On others, the changes may *never* be visible.

In technical terms, there must be a *happens-before* relationship between the write by on thread and the subsequent read by the other thread.  This can be provided by both threads synchronizing on the same mutex or lock, by using a `volatile` variable, and in other ways.  But this code doesn't do any of those things, so there is *no guarantee* that the state change will be visible.

For more details, read about the [Java Memory Model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model).

---

The above is *sufficient* to explain the difference, but there may be a more direct explanation.

In practice, something like a `System.out.println` can lead to changes in the visibility.  Underneath the covers, the `println` call will typically result in synchronization on the output stream's buffers.  That can result in a *serendipitous* happens-before that is sufficient to guarantee visibility.  But this behavior is not specified, so you should not rely on it.

At any rate, adding trace statements can change the behavior of multi-threaded coded.  And the fact that you (apparently) added them in your version is a second possible explanation for the difference.

---

The bottom line here is that a program with a memory visibility flaw is broken, but you may not be able to *demonstrate* that it is broken.

Comment: Actually, the behavior is specified. It’s either of the two outcomes in your list. Further, I wouldn’t call the effect of `println` a “serendipitous happens-before” because it still is not a happens-before relationship. It’s just a visibility side effect (and not necessarily a serendipitous one, as hiding bugs is not a good thing).

Answer (score 1):

As the excellent [Answer by Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71007760/642706) says, your code is not [thread-safe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

Establishing an `AtomicBoolean` early on addresses the visibility problem explained in that other Answer. This class is a thread-safe wrapper around its payload `boolean` value.

The `volatile` keyword is another solution. But I find the `Atomic…` classes simpler and more obvious.

Also, in modern Java we rarely need to address the `Thread` class directly. Instead, use the Executors framework. Define your task as a `Runnable` or `Callable`, and submit to an executor service.

Something like this untested code.

```java
public class Main {
    private static final AtomicBoolean stopRequested = new AtomicBoolean( false ) ;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable task = () -> {
            int i = 0;
            while ( ! stopRequested.get() ) {
                i++;
                System.out.println("i = " + i);
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100); // Don’t spin too fast.
            }
        };
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutorService() ;
        es.submit( task ) ;
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stopRequested.set( true ) ;
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

   // Shut down here executor service. Boilerplate taken from Javadoc.
   es.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!es.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       es.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!es.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Executor service did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     es.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can’t recognize in which regard using `AtomicBoolean` here is “simpler and more obvious”. The example also creates the impression that using the Executors framework had to be horribly more complicated compared to the direct use of `Thread`.